# Capturing SOAP messages using Fiddler

Tags: eclipse, web-services, soap, fiddler

I have created a simple JAX-WS webservice and I am running it on tomcat. I can access the WSDL file at `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldDocStyle/sayhello?wsdl`. So tomcat runs at `http://localhost:8080`.
I also have written a client for this webservice and when I run this client in eclipse it correctly retrieves response from the web-service and displays it in eclipse console.

Now I am trying to capture SOAP traffic between client and web service in [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/). When I put above WSDL link in browser and hit Enter, that request and corresponding response (WSDL file) is getting captured by the fiddler, however when I run the client, it retrieves the response in eclipse console but nothing corresponding to this request-response gets captured in the fiddler. In Fiddler options it is listening to port 8888:

[image]

But I dont understand what else I have to configure in fiddler to capture this traffic between java client and the web service. Am bit weak in proxy and network stuff, but not noob, so please help.

Comment: You either need to set the proxy server in Eclipse to 127.0.0.1:8888, or you need to do the same for your Java runtime. Are you on Windows or another platform?

Comment: yes on Windows patform

Answer (score 0):

First you need to tick the option "Allow remote computers to connect".

Second, you need to ensure that Fiddler is setup as a proxy. This needs amending the your client so that it sends Soap request on localhost:8888 and then add manual proxy from the "Gateway" tab in Fiddler so it forwards request to your service running on http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldDocStyle.